# Makefile: how to assign object to variable and iterate on object of array

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, make

**Makefile:**

```
QUERY := "securityresources | where type == 'microsoft.security/assessments' | summarize by assessmentKey=name | join kind=inner ( securityresources | where type == 'microsoft.security/assessments/subassessments' | extend assessmentKey = extract('.*assessments/(.+?)/.*',1, id) ) on assessmentKey | where properties.additionalData.assessedResourceType == 'ContainerRegistryVulnerability' | extend status = properties.status.code | extend severity = properties.status.severity"

.ONESHELL:
check:
    # az graph query -q ${QUERY}
    results="`az graph query -q ${QUERY}`"
    @for result in $$results.data;
    do
        echo "$${result.status}"
    done
```

Output of `az graph query -q ${QUERY}` looks like:

```
{ "count": 10,
  "data" : [{"status":"healthy", "abc":"123"},
            {"status":"unhealthy", "abc":"322"},
            {"status":"healthy", "abc":"432"}
           ]
}
```

**Error:**

> /bin/bash: line 4: ${result.status}: bad substitution make: ***
>
> [Makefile:23: check] Error 1

How to assign command output to a variable and iterate on that object and access keys, values of those objects?

Comment: What are you expecting `$$results.data` to do? It does not look like a UNIX/Linux question to me.

Comment: @U.Windl `$$results.data` should return array of dictionaries to iterate. Need a right syntax of script(Linux) to run using make file.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `jq` to iterate through JSON.

Something like:

```
az graph query -q ${QUERY} | jq .data[].status
```

Although, not sure how this is related to `make`

Comment: getting `jq` command not found when run using `make`

Comment: @Pythoncoder Install it. The `jq` is not a necessary tool and is not installed from the get go, you have to install it additionally. But it is a well known and exists in all repositories.